# Why cant i get the value from this form using ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, backend

So I'm trying to get the values of this form by using ajax and PHP but for some reason I'm not getting it the way I want to get it. I have tried many ways but its not working.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="array.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
            <form id="form" method="POST" action="array.php">
                    <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="Date">My Birthday is</label>
                            <input type="date"  name="Date" class="form-control" id="Date" placeholder="MM/DD/YY">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="myName">My Name is</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myName" id="myName" placeholder="My Name">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                              <label for="favColor">My Favorite Color is</label>
                                <select name="favColor" class="form-control" id="favColor">
                                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                                    <option value="Red">Red</option>
                                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                                    <option value="Green">Green</option>
                                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
                                    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                                    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
                                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                                </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="mySign">My Sign</label>
                                <select name="mySign" class="form-control" id="mySign">
                                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                                    <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
                                    <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
                                    <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
                                    <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
                                    <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
                                    <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
                                    <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
                                    <option value="Sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
                                    <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
                                    <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
                                    <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
                                </select>
                          </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-right">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </form>


            <div id="test"></div>
```

ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#form').on('submit', function (e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var formData = $(this).serialize();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'array.php',
                    data: {formData: formData},
                    success: function(data){
                      $('#test').append(data);
                    }
                  })
                });
              });
```

PHP

```
$formData = array($_POST["formData"]);

foreach($formData as $d => $d_value){
echo "Key = " . $d . ", Value = " . $d_value;
}
```

What it echo's out

```
Key = 0, Value = Date=2019-11-16&myName=Marco&favColor=Green&mySign=Cancer
```

So what I'm trying to get it to echo out is:

```
Key = 0 , Value = Date=2019, 11, 26
Key = 1 , Value = myName=Marco
Key = 2 , Value = favColor=Green
Key = 3 , Value = mySign=Cancer
```

So does anyone have any suggestions or clues on how I can fix this because I've tried other things but it still does not echo it the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
data: {formData: formData},
```

in your `$.ajax` call with

```
data: formData,
```

Then in your PHP script you will have each of the values separately in `$_POST` i.e.

```
$_POST['Date'] = '2019, 11, 26';
$_POST['myName'] = 'Marco';
$_POST['favColor'] = 'Green';
$_POST['mySign'] = 'Cancer';
```